# variables in QueryString

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm new to QueryString. My issue is:

-I need to pass a cookie value through an URL that exists already to a third party application that can collect information from the URL.

-I am able to get the cookie value through javascript. The value is stored in a variable named, say, test1.

How can I use this "test1" variable in QueryString, that's going to change depending on the user that's logged in? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the query string in the URL to the third party application:

```
var url = 'http://servername/path/to/application?param=' + encodeURIComponent(test1);
```

Comment: Thank You! this worked!The third party is able to pull the data I need it to.